# Why is my cpu overheating when i use i3wm?

Tags: linux-mint, i3, temperature

I've got a laptop running linux mint cinnamon 17.3
I'm currently playing with/learning/considering to switch to i3wm.

When I'm on cinnamon, the cpu temp is around 40-45°C (104 - 113 F)
But when I use i3wm, the temp rises to 65°C (149 F). Nothing dramatic, but i'd like to fix it anyway, because the fan becomes very noisy to evacuate the excess of heat.

I'm using TLP.

Has anyone ever had the same problem/knows how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the cpu load increasing as well?

Comment: Maybe TLP doesn't run in your i3wm session? Have you checked that?

Comment: Hi. I checked TLP. it's running in i3wm.

Comment: cpu max freq is 2.7GHz. in i3wm it's constantly at 2.4, almost max load.

Comment: It only occurs when I logout from cinnamon to switch to i3. Problem solved. Thanks for the replies anyway